# Interpolate shape (3d analyst) problem

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap

I am making a code on C# to interpolate z values of a line on a DEM. Below is the code that I've written. I have also tried step by step debugging, the program works fine till the Geoprocessor execution. But on Geoprocessor execution, it crashes the ArcGIS. What could be the problem:::

IMxDocument CurrentDocument = (ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IMxDocument)ArcMap.Document;
            IMap MapSelected = CurrentDocument.FocusMap;

```
        //The code below is to fetch the Raster Layer having name equal to what selected in combo box
        int LayerIndex = 0;
        string LayerName;
        string comboText = (string)comboDEM.SelectedItem;

        for (int i = 0; i < MapSelected.LayerCount; i++)
        {
            LayerName = MapSelected.get_Layer(i).Name;

            if (LayerName == comboText)
            {
                LayerIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        Geoprocessor GP = new Geoprocessor();
        ILayer RasterLayer = MapSelected.get_Layer(LayerIndex);

        InterpolateShape Interpolator = new InterpolateShape();
        Interpolator.in_surface = RasterLayer;

        //The code below is to fetch the Feature Layer having name equal to what is given in textbox
        string XS_Line = txtInputCrossSectionLine.Text;
        for (int i = 0; i < MapSelected.LayerCount; i++)
        {
            LayerName = MapSelected.get_Layer(i).Name;

            if (LayerName == XS_Line)
            {
                LayerIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        ILayer FeatureLayer = MapSelected.get_Layer(LayerIndex);
        Interpolator.in_feature_class = FeatureLayer;
        Interpolator.out_feature_class = @"E:\For Arc GIS\Data\ResultFromTIN";

        GP.Execute(Interpolator, null);
```